# Split large file using awk

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I have a large file I need to split using the 6th column unique values but the columns are separated by ~

How can I achieve this using the "awk" command in Ubuntu.? My text file is huge and has more than 400,000 rows.

Thanks in advance.

```
    2016~02~ MP~0639161~0090~13~177~0081~02~0200~ .8500~     8.8500~         27.00~0530~9970~                TAYA~1.000~          33.0~          40.0~      8,124 ~        905 ~        425 ~            ~00060~2006~              ~              ~ ~              ~2007~              ~              ~ ~              ~2008~              ~              ~ ~              ~2009~              ~              ~T~          47.0~2010~        481.70~         24.80~A~          19.0~2011~              ~              ~Z~              ~2012~        261.90~         24.80~A~          11.0~2013~              ~              ~Z~              ~2014~      1,349.33~         24.90~A~          54.0~2015~              ~              ~Z~              ~          ~  ~        0.00~          0.00
    2016~02~ MP~0639161~0080~13~177~0081~02~0200~ .8500~     8.8500~         18.40~0530~9970~                TAYA~1.000~          40.0~          45.0~      6,237 ~        554 ~        260 ~            ~00120~2006~              ~              ~ ~              ~2007~              ~              ~ ~              ~2008~              ~              ~ ~              ~2009~              ~              ~ ~              ~2010~              ~              ~T~          47.0~2011~              ~              ~T~          47.0~2012~        211.00~         18.40~A~          11.0~2013~              ~              ~Z~              ~2014~      1,038.34~         18.40~A~          56.0~2015~              ~              ~Z~              ~          ~  ~        0.00~          0.00
    2016~02~ MP~0639166~0020~34~033~0011~02~0102~ .5000~     5.1300~         25.00~0030~0110~                    ~ .500~          62.0~          62.0~      1,988 ~         70 ~         23 ~            ~00170~2004~      5,234.00~        103.70~A~          50.0~2005~      6,481.00~         94.40~A~          69.0~2006~      3,308.00~         56.30~A~          59.0~2007~      6,548.00~         96.10~A~          68.0~2008~      2,679.00~         40.00~A~          67.0~2011~      2,226.00~         39.40~A~          56.0~2012~              ~              ~Z~              ~2013~      1,766.00~         40.00~A~          44.0~2014~      3,129.50~         36.20~A~          86.0~2015~              ~              ~Z~              ~          ~  ~        0.00~          0.00
```

Output 1:

```
2016~02~ MP~0639161~0090~13~177~0081~02~0200~ .8500~     8.8500~         27.00~0530~9970~                TAYA~1.000~          33.0~          40.0~      8,124 ~        905 ~        425 ~            ~00060~2006~              ~              ~ ~              ~2007~              ~              ~ ~              ~2008~              ~              ~ ~              ~2009~              ~              ~T~          47.0~2010~        481.70~         24.80~A~          19.0~2011~              ~              ~Z~              ~2012~        261.90~         24.80~A~          11.0~2013~              ~              ~Z~              ~2014~      1,349.33~         24.90~A~          54.0~2015~              ~              ~Z~              ~          ~  ~        0.00~          0.00
2016~02~ MP~0639161~0080~13~177~0081~02~0200~ .8500~     8.8500~         18.40~0530~9970~                TAYA~1.000~          40.0~          45.0~      6,237 ~        554 ~        260 ~            ~00120~2006~              ~              ~ ~              ~2007~              ~              ~ ~              ~2008~              ~              ~ ~              ~2009~              ~              ~ ~              ~2010~              ~              ~T~          47.0~2011~              ~              ~T~          47.0~2012~        211.00~         18.40~A~          11.0~2013~              ~              ~Z~              ~2014~      1,038.34~         18.40~A~          56.0~2015~              ~              ~Z~              ~          ~  ~        0.00~          0.00
```

Output 2:

```
2016~02~ MP~0639166~0020~34~033~0011~02~0102~ .5000~     5.1300~         25.00~0030~0110~                    ~ .500~          62.0~          62.0~      1,988 ~         70 ~         23 ~            ~00170~2004~      5,234.00~        103.70~A~          50.0~2005~      6,481.00~         94.40~A~          69.0~2006~      3,308.00~         56.30~A~          59.0~2007~      6,548.00~         96.10~A~          68.0~2008~      2,679.00~         40.00~A~          67.0~2011~      2,226.00~         39.40~A~          56.0~2012~              ~              ~Z~              ~2013~      1,766.00~         40.00~A~          44.0~2014~      3,129.50~         36.20~A~          86.0~2015~              ~              ~Z~              ~          ~  ~        0.00~          0.00
```

Comment: Done: Please see my edit.

Comment: Which one is your sixth field (based on white space or ~) and what happened to the third record after split?

Comment: 6th field numbers are: 13 and 34 in this example but I have more 6th field numbers in the text file. I have not posted all the rows in the example here. But, I want separate files for each 6th field unique number for example based on the above 13 and 34.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creates output file name like 13.txt, 34.txt, ...**,

when you run second time, don't forget to delete previously created files as it appends `>>`

```
awk -F'~' '{f=$6".txt";  print >> f; close(f)}' file
```

**Creates output file name like Output_1.txt, Output_2.txt, ...**

This one takes care of overwriting, so no need of worrying when you run second time

```
awk -F'~' '          # call awk set field sep ~
 !($6 in F){         # if $6 as index does not exist in array F then


      # if you want to create filename by 6th field value
      # 13.txt, 34.txt ...
      # then just make F[$6]=$6".txt";

      # Created output file like Output_1.txt, Output_2.txt
      F[$6]="Output_"++i".txt"; 

      # write record to file, close file and go to next line
      print >F[$6]; close(F[$6]); next
 }
 {
   # append record to file, and close file
   print >>F[$6]; close(F[$6])
 }' file
```

Comment: @ Akshay: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted. Appreciate it a lot. This exactly produces what I want. Thanks again.

Comment: you may want to trim the white space when not using the default FS, otherwise which might sneak in to the filenames.

Comment: @Akshay: Your second command does not producing "Output_49.txt" but your first command produced 49.txt. Either way, I can use your first command not a problem. Thanks bunch again.

Comment: @user3408139: I edited my post, and also added comment, with `F[$6]=$6".txt"` you will get filename based on 6th field value, and with `F[$6]="Output_"++i".txt"` you will get filename incremental, not based on the value of 6th field, I also added limitations of 1st command, in second run it will append, so you have to delete newly created files

Comment: @Akshay: I ran your updated code but still it does not producing the "Output_49.txt" and I also checked the original text file I am using and it has 6th column value for 49. Your 1st command does produced 49.txt and it contains all the rows which contains the 6th column values of 49. I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: @user3408139: did you change `F[$6]="Output_"++i".txt";` to `F[$6]=$6".txt"` ?

Comment: @Akshay: Yes I did. I ran both ways. When I change to "Output_"++i".txt" it does not produce the Output_49.txt file. But, when I change to $6".txt" it produced 49.txt file. I checked the original file as well and it does have 6th column values of 49.

Comment: @EdMorton: What I am missing, what to correct, I didn't get you sorry

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood part of what you're doing, I see now you need the `>>`s because you;re closing the output file after every write. Are you sure the OP doesn't have access to gawk and then none of that is necessary?

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't know, OP hasn't specified much about his environment, so thought this would be portable, even I have no idea whether file is sorted.